# Apache Installation

Tags: apache

I just installed Apache 2.2.x in my windows 7 x64. everything seemed okey and I am getting the "It works!" page. However when I tried to edit the index.html in htdocs and I display localhost again it just says "It works!" it didnt show the modifications that I did on the file. Is this an indication of something wrong with my installation?

Comment: I think it's a caching problem. Did you try restarting Apache or clearing the browser cache?

Answer (score 2):

I believe to change the index.html in win7x64 , you need to run your editor as an administrator , as it is located in program files folder , and to change anything in program files folder or any folder under it you need to run the editor as admin

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your browser isn't caching the default page.  After you make a change to your index.html, clear your browser cache and try again.

If that still doesn't work, ensure you're not editing the wrong index.html file; the default site may be pointing to a different location than the one you're editing.  (I'd guess the issue is the browser cache, however...)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-F5 the page for hard refresh.

If same page is there:

A) you're editing the wrong index.html/php file.

B) you're making edits that don't change the output.

If you can't get it to work, I suggest you install a full [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) package.